# Compare two files in Erlang

Tags: file, erlang, compare

I have two different files. First file look like this:

```
hallo
bye
something
new
```

And in second file I have eg. bye. From name of second file (eg. msg-0002) I know that this message must be second in first file. How can I, in Erlang, find that particularly word in first file? I just have to see if the second word is really bye.

That's the code I made so far:

```
-module(compare).
-export([compare/0]).

compare () ->
    {ok, Pars} = file:read_file("words.txt"),
    {ok, Dump} = file:read_file("msg-0002.file"), 
    L1 = binary:split(Pars, <<"\n">>, [global]).
    L2 = binary:split(Dump, <<"\n">>, [global]).
```

In this code I get all the words in lists. I don't know how to get from name of msg-0002 file that word must be in 2. place in first file. And how to check if this particularly word is really in eg. second place in first file? That's important.

Comment: You mean like `lists:nth(2, L1) == lists:nth(1, L2)`? (Check if the second element in L1 is equal to the first in L2.)

Comment: I can't follow the question. You should provide both lists and the the result you expect from the `compare` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to extract the line number from the file name (assuming the file names are always of the form "msg-XXX.file":

```
FileName = "msg-0002.file",
{ok,[NumLine],_} = io_lib:fread("msg-~d.file",FileName),
```

and then to check if the 2 files are consistent, use Dogbert proposal:

```
{ok, Pars} = file:read_file("words.txt"),
{ok, Dump} = file:read_file(FileName),
L1 = binary:split(Pars, <<"\n">>, [global]),
L2 = binary:split(Dump, <<"\n">>, [global]),
Check = lists:nth(NumLine, L1) == lists:nth(1, L2),
...
```

Comment: `lists:nth(1, L2)` is an overly elaborate way to say `hd(L2)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how you can do it, for example in escript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript

main(["-q"|ARGS]) ->
    compare(ARGS, true);
main(ARGS) ->
    compare(ARGS, false).

compare([MsgFile, WordsFile], Quiet) ->
    case io_lib:fread("msg-~d", MsgFile) of
        {ok, [N], _} when N > 0 ->
            Msg  = read_msg(MsgFile),
            Word = read_nth(WordsFile, N),
            case Msg =:= Word of
                true ->
                    Quiet orelse io:put_chars("Yes\n"),
                    halt(0);
                false ->
                    Quiet orelse io:put_chars("No\n"),
                    halt(1)
            end;
        _ -> usage()
    end;
compare(_, _) ->
    usage().

read_msg(File) ->
    {ok, FH} = file:open(File, [read, binary]),
    {ok, Msg} = file:read_line(FH),
    ok = file:close(FH),
    Msg.

read_nth(File, N) ->
    {ok, FH} = file:open(File, [raw, read, binary, read_ahead]),
    Word = read_nth_(FH, N),
    ok = file:close(FH),
    Word.

read_nth_(FH, N) ->
    case file:read_line(FH) of
        {ok, Word} when N =:= 1 -> Word;
        {ok, _} -> read_nth_(FH, N-1);
        Error -> error({words_file, Error})
    end.

usage() ->
    io:format(standard_error, "~ts [-q] <msg-file> <words-file>~n"
              "\t<msg-file> - must have name in form msg-N*~n",
              [escript:script_name()]),
    halt(255).
```